# Как удалить неиспользуемый JavaScript код для ускорения сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, оптимизация-сайтов

какой самый оптимальный способ удаления неиспользуемого js кода? PageSpeed Insights ругается. js-файл весом 700 кб работает всего на 1%. 99% не работает вообще. Ручным способом наверное очень долго, тем более файл у меня не один.

Обнаружить его не проблема, с этим справился. Но дальше как удалить весь инет перерыл так и ничего не нашел. Есть решение от гугла, но для меня сложно понять всё что там пишут. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/unused-javascript/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=lr.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, загруженное не выгружается. Может просто стоит вручную все неиспользуемое удалить?

Comment: Да это дебилизм угождать всем хотелкам PageSpeed, я однажды сделал 99% оптимизации, но это мне стоило 2 недель потраченных. Хрень это в общем, если у вас на сайте js кэшируется, то PageSpeed будет ругаться на этот именно фаил, а он в свою очередь вбирает в себя почти все скрипты. А есть скрипты, которые разработчик хорошо написал и они не отрабатывают на странице, где нет элемента, с которым нужно взаимодействовать, а PageSpeed считает этот код js неиспользуемым.